# Do the "quadratic formula relations" have any significance?

Tags: reference-request, quadratics

With the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ in mind, I'd like to know if the relations
$$
s_a(x)=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4xc}}{2x},\quad s_b(x)=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4ac}}{2a},\quad s_c(x)=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ax}}{2a}
$$
are ever useful and if not, why?

My guess is "no" since they don't seem to be part of any standard mathematics curriculum (that I've encountered). The guess is strengthened by the lack of results I find on Google.

Even then, I feel that it is a natural curiosity for any student learning about the quadratic formula to try and graph the output of the quadratic formula against $a,b$ or $c$. [The graphs of each relation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vynac5q5ny) reveal some interesting patterns of solutions for quadratic equations depending on how $a,b,c$ change.

Comment: It’s rare that you want to consider what happens to the roots when you vary just one of the coefficients. These are all just a relabeling of the standard formula, so I don’t really see a reason why anyone would consider them separately.

Comment: Suppose that $~A~$ and $~X~$ are each **fixed** real numbers such that $$AX^2 + bX + c = 0 ~~\text{and} ~~XA^2 + bA + c = 0.$$  I don't see any (subtle) relationship between $~A~$ and $~X.$